# delayed loading of template file inside bootstrap modal

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, magento-1.7

I have integrated bootstrap modal into Magento eCommerce within my custom them and it works really well except for one problem: a 2 second delay in loading the content of the modal when using a .phtml template file.

If I use a.html file stored in a directory off of the root folder, it loads seamlessly without any delay and it looks beautiful.  Likewise, if I embed my modal content into the same page, it also loads properly.

Unfortunately neither of these are really an option: using .html precludes being able to use php scripting inside the modal partial when I need it and I do not want to clutter up the page by embedding the modal content; I want to keep them separated in their own partials.

The module I wrote is rather simple with the controller containing just the following:

```
public function rebatesAction(){
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('partials/modals/rebates.phtml');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
```

My question is, how do I eliminate that 2 second delay when loading my modal content using this approach?  Or, is there is different approach that I have not listed here which would resolve this issue?

Comment: Eitherway put the content directly in the template via layout.xml and just toggle it... or get a better server, unfortunatly magento is a real slowpoke. Just ho

Comment: @Soundz: do you mean local.xml inside design>frontend>myTheme>layout>local.xml?

Comment: @Soundz: I tried calling my .phtml file directly inside of my page with getChildHtml(); and it does something odd: when accessing the modal for the first time, my partial content appears for about 2 seconds and then disappears completely and does not return when the modal is subsequently called.

Comment: yep, if you try call `getChildHtml()` you need to tell your block it has childhtml

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution to this issue:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('moduleName/blockType')->setTemplate('moduleName/templateName.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

It's probably the least elegant way of doing this in Magento but it works.  I'm sure the better way would be to use local.xml inside of the layout directory within your theme, but I can't figure it out at the moment on my own.